# Ошибка подключения FreeType " undefined reference to `FT_Init_FreeType' "

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Пишу игру на OpenGL, мне надо выводить текст на экран, нашёл статью как это делать с FreeType, но там (да вообще нигде) не объясняют как её ставить. Я так понимаю ошибка выше из-за того что я не подключил библиотеки (файлы расширения .a и .dll (хотя наверно у этой библиотеки dll нет)).
Скачивал с официального сайта https://freetype.org/ а именно с https://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/.
В зипах нет папки с библиотеками, а при сборке cmake получается какая-то ерунда.
Вызываю контекст окна с помощью GLFW, может кто знает как в нём сделать это проще? Мне подойдёт любой вариант как вывести текст на экран, ГЛАВНО чтобы шрифты можно было грузить с ttf и/или чтоб библиотека была кроссплатформенная (хотя бы чтоб была возможность компиляции под Android и Windows)

Папка с собранным FreeType выглядит так: [image: Папка с собранным FreeType]
Мне кажется она не должна так выглядеть, там всё же надо библиотеки, а их нет.
Ещё в примерах показано подключение ft2build.h которого нет в данной папке.

Comment: Ну ты бы поклацал хотя-бы сайт, как минимум я вот такое нашёл: https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/index.html , и даже такое: https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html#section-1

Comment: Freetype - хороший выбор. Давайте подробнее про *"при сборке cmake получается какая-то ерунда"*, я ее использую и у меня все нормально собирается.

Comment: Насчёт папки с собранным FreeType я поправил, а насчёт ссылок которые скинул Ellenord, я там был, я много чего просмотрел, там написана линковка библиотек, но для линковки нужны сами библиотеки которых нет...

Comment: Пишите `@username`, когда отвечаете в комментариях, а то нам не приходят уведомления. Пробовали искать в подпапках? Где-то там должны быть `.a` или `.lib`, в зависимости от компилятора (кстати, какой компилятор?). Или, каноничнее было бы для CMake указать `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=путь`, после сборки сделать `make install`, и тогда в указанную папку скопируются и нужные библиотеки, и хедеры.

Comment: Если это игровой проект, то имеет смысл использовать SDF ну или хотя бы пиксельные шрифты, а не связываться с болотом freetype.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я обыскал всю папку собранного проекта при помощи поисковика и *.a, ничего не нашлось, а DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ставится автоматически C:/Program Files (x86)/freetype, но по этому пути такой папки нет, возможно у cmake не достаточно доступа, я пробовал собрать другую библиотеку меняя DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX на папку, в котором собираю проект, но и тогда папка тоже не создавалась.

Comment: И по поводу компилятора, пишу проект в Sublime Text при помощи make и g++ (gcc, MinGW64)

Comment: Ну как всегда я не внимательный) Дочитал, сделал, lib и include создались, сейчас попробую запустить

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё заработало, напишите это как ответ, я его отмечу как решение.

Comment: Тогда я напишу чтоб вопрос так не висел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтоб самому собрать FreeType надо сначала собрать его через CMake (в CMake в строке `DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` надо вписать путь, куда будет собираться библиотека уже через make), а после в папке, в которой собралась библиотека, собрать через make (в папке указанной в `DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` будут собраны библиотеки и include файлы).

PS: Спасибо @HolyBlackCat.

Answer (score 0):

Используй это: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg

Открываешь **PowerShell**, заходишь в какую нибудь папку куда можно склонировать репозиторий, и вперёд:

```powershell
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
cd vcpkg
.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
.\vcpkg search freetype
```

После чего выбираешь что тебе из этого надо, и устанавливаешь через `.\vcpkg install [packages to install]`

[image: vcpkg search example]

Comment: Это если компилятор - MSVC... Для MinGW там какие-то пляски с бубном вроде.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну такое, типа добавляешь в СMake options `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=[vcpkg root]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake` - и радуешься жизни.

Comment: Ну, как минимум нужно как-то приказать vcpkg билдить свои пакеты в mingw. И плюс еще ["MinGW is not tested as part of vcpkg repository's CI process, so regressions can occur"](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-docs/blob/main/vcpkg/users/platforms/mingw.md), что тоже не может не радовать. В этом плане мне MSYS2 как-то больше нравится. У них MinGW - основное направление, поэтому у них такой фигни не будет.

Comment: Всё сделал по инструкции, может я чего-то не понимаю, но и тут нет файлов .a, только dll и .lib, но вроде .lib для mcvs.